# Supabase calls outdated function even when it is deleted

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I've created a new function in Supabase as follows:

```
drop function if exists select_whitelist_airdrop_address;
create
or replace function select_whitelist_airdrop_address(airdrop_address text)
returns table(owner text, hash text)
as $$
select a.owner, b.hash
from thirdparty_token_holders a
         left join thirdparty_token_airdrops b
                   on a.id = b.holder_id
where (b.status = 1 AND b.hash != 'NOT PROCESSED' AND a.owner=airdrop_address)
    limit 1
$$ language sql;
```

And deleted an older one called select_whitelist_airdrops. Upon deleting it, I've started getting the following error:

```
info: getAirdropWhitelistStatus -> error: {"error":{"message":"Could not find the public.select_whitelist_airdrops(hash) function or the public.select_whitelist_airdrops function with
a single unnamed json or jsonb parameter in the schema cache","hint":"If a new function was created in the database with this name and parameters, try reloading the schema cache."},"da
ta":null,"count":null,"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","body":null}
```

Why is Supabase referring to this function when:

1. I no longer need it
2. I am using another function in my code, see below:

```
  public async getAirdropWhitelistStatus(address: string) {
    return this.supabase.rpc('select_whitelist_airdrop_address', {
      airdrop_address: address
    })
  }
```

Why does Supabase keep referring back to the old proc when run?